# Cannot access AppDelegate while testing Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, unit-testing

```
func testExample() {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    // some code ...
}
```

The above function always crash and gives this error:

> Could not cast value of type 'MyAppName.AppDelegate' (0x10dc09e80) to 'MyAppNameTests.AppDelegate' (0x11cc190c0).

Answer (score 3):

You are probably compiling AppDelegate into your test target. Don't do this.

Instead, only compile into your normal app target MyAppName. In you test class write in XCode 7

```
@testable import MyAppName
```

and before XCode 7

```
import MyAppName
```

Comment: writing "@testable import MyAppName" in my test class gives me this error:  Unknown attribute 'testable'

Comment: Then you don't use XCode 7. Before XCode 7 remove '@testable'.

Comment: that did not work, too

Comment: Same error message? Are sure that the target of AppDelegate is not MyAppNameTest?

Comment: @GerdCastan can you elaborate on your answer a bit? Why is compiling into your test target bad? How can I "only compile into your normal app target". I have a similar issue, but when I 'import MyAppName' I get 'No such module "MyAppName"', which I suspect is about something I don't understand, but *you do*...

Comment: Replace MyAppName in the import statement exactly with the name of the target you chose for your App. I hope you have chosen to have no space in that target name.