# Cannot cast App Delegate to App Delegate in Tests

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I'm doing Unit Tests in Swift, and am running into a problem. Every time I run the tests, I get the error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'app.AppDelegate' to 'app_Tests.AppDelegate'
```

I made sure that the AppDelegate was unchecked from the tests bundle, and the view controllers cannot access the app delegate anymore. Does anyone have a solution to this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: hi, is it what you expected, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31990724/cannot-access-appdelegate-in-xctestcase-objects-or-anything-that-references-it keep me informed

Comment: I think you will be looking something similar to the answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/32161983/2010154

Answer (score 5):

I think your `view controllers` has checked `target membership` in your test bundle. In this case you `view controllers` uses your tests module and App Delegate your real module.

[image: Target Membership]

If you have in your test file `@testable import <module name>` in the top, where  your app name, for example `app`. Then you should have ability to your `view controllers` without checked `target membership` for your tests.

This thing comes with Swift 2.0 that was released in September 2015.

Comment: I have tried your solution.But if I have written method in my viewcontroller(ex:func getEmail()) means I could not call that method in my test.How to call those method in test target.

Comment: should that method be a public method?

Comment: @Madhumitha nope, `@testable import` mean you could use internal methods, too. But not private.