# Cannot cast App Delegate to App Delegate in XCTest

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unit-testing, xctest

I am working in an ios app in Xcode 7.3.1.In that I am trying to start unit testing on my swift iOS app. I cannot see to access anything that uses my appDelegate.I tried the following to solve from the following.But still am getting the same issue.Please help me to solve this.
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28042105/swift-dynamic-cast-failed-error-when-trying-to-run-unit-tests),
[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31179382/cannot-access-appdelegate-while-testing-xcode-project)

I am getting the following issue,while i am running unit test.
My sample code is

```
import UIKit
import XCTest

@testable import MyAppName

class FreshBossTests: XCTestCase {

    var login:LoginPageController!
    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        login = LoginPageController()
    }
    override func tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }
    func testlogin() {
        let email:String! = "xxx@gmail.com"
        if login.isValidEmail(email) == true {
            XCTAssertEqual(true, true,"email in valid  format")
        }
    }
```

In my LoginPageController,I am having the following code.

```
let appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
```

In that line only am getting the error like

```
Could not cast value of type 'MyAppName.AppDelegate' (0x10dc09e80) to 'MyAppNameTests.AppDelegate' (0x11cc190c0).
```

Comment: show your relevant code?

Comment: you app is called MyAppName? really? really?

Comment: no.. I have given that name for sample..

Answer (score 2):

You can import the production module at the top of the XCTest file.

`@testable import MyAppName`

This will then let you cast like:

Swift 3

`let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! MyAppName.AppDelegate`

Answer (score 0):

As matt suggest, use it like `ProductModuleName.AppDelegate`. So in your case it would be

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! MyAppName.AppDelegate
```

`MyAppName` should be the name of your app target module, not your test target. If you are unsure about the module name search `Product Module Name` in app target build settings

Comment: I tried the same.But "Use of undeclared type MyAppName" getting this error

Comment: check the product module name in target build setting. are you sure `MyAppName ` is the module name. App name and module name can be different

Answer (score 0):

In your setup() function instead of "login = LoginPageController()"
use these lines

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType))
    login = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginView") as! LoginPageController
```

I faced the same issue and this helped me out.